# Copy (Backup) data from one server to another (backup) server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, service, ftp

I am developing application and confuse to use which approach to copy or backup my all the files from one server (source) to another server (backup) server periodically.

[image]

I have to get backup of my all the files including databases from one server to another periodically (every 7 days).

I think one way that is implementing Window Services on the Server 1 (Source server) and implementing Web services on the another server (Backup server).

On Web services I will use the FTP to accept files and store it and on the Window services I will sent that files.

Questions:

1. Above approach is correct to implement the backup server? Or there is any other way to do this?
2. How I will backup my database and store it on the backup server?
3. There is possible to show Progress bar when we using FTP to send files on the backup server.
4. Files size may be larger than 5 GB.
5. There is any another way to implement this type of architecture or solve this type of problems?

Comment: Why don't you use backup software to do this?

Comment: Consider using Azure. Then all these problems vanish. For files, the storage service in Azure already creates 3 copies of all data, or 6 times if you want a geographically different area to store them in. SQL Server Azure already does backup - how many days back is a pricing issue.

Comment: If Server 2 (backup server) is accessible through FTP then it doesn't need any web service...if server 1 (db server) has a windows service (or a scheduled operation!) to perform backup and upload (separate operations...) then WHO will see that progress bar?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Thanks, Forget progress bar. But this approach is good to implement ? And if backup server is not accessible through the FTP so what approach we have to follow to solve this problem?

Comment: @PedroG.Dias, Thanks, But I can not use the Azure and any third party software or server to implement this. We have own servers on the different different region.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai good/reliable error handling isn't easy. First of all I'd store backup locally (on server 1) using task A. Separate Windows service should monitor output directory and perform uploading (retrying in case of errors). If all attempts (let's say 3) fail then it may schedule itself for another attempt later (one hour?), if also that attempt fails then administrator must be warned (e-mail?) and one last attempt may be tried. Attempts may even be delayed to next day to workaround temporary network errors. Proper strategy isn't an easy choice

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks man, For showing me all the cases. I really does not think all about it. It look like I have to do RnD from the first. Thanks Man,Can you help me to show some direction or methodology or any architecture to solve this problem? It would be great help to me.

Comment: Unfortunately resources are pretty sparse, few scripts to do backup, commands to automate backup execution, code to upload via FTP and custom code (in some language) to perform error handling. If you're not using a backup program it may be a lot of code to write (and test!).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107635/discussion-between-kalpesh-rajai-and-adriano-repetti).

Comment: @KalpeshRajai have you got any solution for this question.I'm looking for solution to automaticaly copy file from one server to other which is in different environment. i've got access of both environment.  Thanks